# how to hide existing uicontrol in Matlab before printing figure?

Tags: matlab

I am using a Matlab based program that does some nice plots of some model results. It adds uicontrol slides and buttons in figures. I have no expierence with gui programming in Matlab, and I dont need it, I just wanna add on my matlab script a couple of lines to hide slides and buttons. I can do it manually from the property editor and set "Visible" to "off", but I was reading the Matlab manual and it does not explain how to retrieve an existing uicontrol and change its properties. Any hint? I tried this with no luck:

b = get(gcf,'uicontrol');
set(b,'Style','pushbutton','Visible','off');

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to access the element from the handles structure and change its property from there.

For example, if the pushbutton is stored in the handles structure like this:

```
handles.b %// Whatever name you gave it and see in the Property Inspector
```

you can make it not visible using the command

```
set(handles.b,'Visible','off')
```

and likewise for every other properties.

Little trick: If you need to repeatedly turn on and off elements of your GUI, you can put them in an array of handles for example in the `Opening_Fcn` of the GUI and change them all at once using this array anywhere in the GUI. This way you won't have to always call them one by one which can be tedious.

Example:

```
handles.AllButtons = [handles.button1; handles.button2; handles.button3]
```

this contains the handles to 3 pushbuttons let's say. Now if yu need to turn them all off/on at the same time, you can do:

```
set(handles.AllButtons,'Visible','off')
```

instead of doing

```
set(handles.button1,'Visible','off')
set(handles.button2,'Visible','off')
set(handles.button3,'Visible','off')
```

From GUIDE, you can check the actual name of any uicontrol component in the Property Inspector. Here is a screenshot from a GUI I made with GUIDE:

[image]

In this case, the Tag associated with the button is `pushbutton28_ReferenceChannelApply`.

Therefore, in order to change any of its properties I would need to use:

```
set(handles.pushbutton28_ReferenceChannelApply,'Property','value')
```

**EDIT 2**

You can look for pushbuttons in your GUI with the `findobj` command like so:

```
FindButtons = findobj('Style','push')
```

which will output an array of handles to those pushbuttons. Then you can query their properties using the `get` command:

```
get(FindButtons(1))
```

Comment: My problems is to get the handles of the uicontrol. Since I did not create them, I have no idea what the handles are!

Comment: Mmm I have this figure with the slider and button that is created by a Matlab-based software (I dont have the source code, it is compiled). I opened guide (lowercase) it asked my to load an existing gui. The only thing I came up with is saving the figure and loading it in guide. I pressed the inspector button, but the tag field is empty. Is it really so hard to get the handles? There should be a command from the command line...

Comment: awesome then glad to help!